# Как воспроизвести mp3 c помощью pyglet в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собственно, мой вопрос в теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для примера ниже использую pyglet вместе с библиотекой `avbin`:

```
import pyglet
import os

def play(file_name):
    dll_file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'avbin')
    pyglet.lib.load_library(dll_file_name)

    player = pyglet.media.Player()
    source = pyglet.media.load(file_name)
    player.queue(source)

    player.play()

    def update(dt):
        if not player.playing:
            # Отпишем функцию, иначе при повторном вызове, иначе
            # будет двойной вызов при следующем воспроизведении
            pyglet.clock.unschedule(update)
            pyglet.app.exit()

    # Every 500 ms / 0.5 sec
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 0.5)
    pyglet.app.run()


play('speak.mp3')
```

Алгоритм довольно простой:

- создание объекта-плеера
- создание медиа источника
- добавление его в очередь плеера
- запуск плеера и цикла обработки событий `pyglet`
- чтобы скрипт не завис после окончания воспроизведения, создается планировщик, который каждые полсекунды вызывает функцию
- функция планировщика проверяет плеер на активность и если он закончил воспроизведение, то отписывается из планировщика и убивает цикл обработки событий.

[Рабочий пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/play%20mp3) (только для windows из-за `avbin.dll`, однако avbin кроссплатформеная библиотека, так что это проблема) можно посмотреть на моей странице github.